# app stops using fragments with Countdown timer

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, crash, crash-reports

I'm New to Android.
I'm moving two fragments over a countdown timer.
after 10 seconds the next fragment should appear but my app stops working.
I tried some solution but couldn't find fit for it.
Please help me.

Question3.java (First fragment)

```
package com.example.sheikhspc.testapp;


import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Question3 extends Fragment  {


public Question3() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
CountDownTimer timer;
int score;
Fragment frag;
TextView tv, scr;
View view;
ImageView imageView1, imageViewR, imageView2;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question3, container, false);

    tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.timer3);
    imageView1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wrong1);
    imageViewR = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.right);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.wrong2);


    timer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("done!");
            frag = new Question4();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, frag);

            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }

    };
    timer.start();


    return view;
}

}
```

Question4.java (Second fragment)

```
package com.example.sheikhspc.testapp;


import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Question4 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {


public Question4() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
Fragment frag;
TextView tv;
View view1;
CountDownTimer timer;
ImageView imageView1, imageViewR, imageView2;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question4, container, false);

    tv = (TextView)view1.findViewById(R.id.timer4);
    imageView1 = (ImageView) view1.findViewById(R.id.wrong1);
    imageViewR = (ImageView) view1.findViewById(R.id.right);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) view1.findViewById(R.id.wrong2);
    imageView1.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageViewR.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView2.setOnClickListener(this);

    timer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            tv.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("done!");
            frag = new Question5();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, frag);

            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }

    };
    timer.start();




    return view1;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
}
}
```

Error Log

```
E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 12695052 byte  allocation with 7472568 free bytes and 7MB until OOM"
D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.sheikhspc.testapp, PID: 21504
              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 12695052 byte allocation with 7472568 free bytes and 7MB until OOM
                  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2477)
                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2384)
                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
                  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3742)
                  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:149)
                  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:145)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1013)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1072)
                  at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                  at com.example.sheikhspc.testapp.Question4.onCreateView(Question4.java:36)
                  at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                  at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1454)
                  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21504 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: The log shows that it an OutOfMemoryError. Are you using large bitmaps in fragment. If yes, then you have to recycle the bitmap variables once it's use has been finished to let the gc() cleanup the memory occupied by the bitmap.

Comment: Yeah i get that there is some problem with memory. Can you please guide me a little that where is I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: it shows error in this line of second fragment

   **view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question4, container, false);**

I dont what i've done wrong. Same project was running good.

Comment: It could be the issue in your layout. Are you setting a large size image in your R.layout.fragment_question4? because OutOfMemory occurring when the app loading the layout in memory.

Comment: Just Added the **android:largeHeap="true"** in the manifest and it solved my problem

Comment: It works because it increase for the app memory size but your issue is memory leak. So finding & fixing it is better otherwise it might impact on your app performance depend on the usage.

Comment: Can you please guide me through this that how i can find memory leaks.
You are right. this isn't the solution but i don't have enough knowledge about this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following code in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/guruji"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:largeHeap="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```